# Adcolony video ios

Tags: adcolony

I implement ADColony but find error Please see code and logs of error. 
1:[AdColony configureWithAppID:@"app734192e5ab9a4025b9"zoneIDs:@[@"vz2f9f9a691d6443aca0"] delegate:self logging:YES];

-(void)VideoAddMethod:(UIButton*)bt
{

```
[AdColony playVideoAdForZone:@"vz2f9f9a691d6443aca0" withDelegate:nil];
```

// [AdColony playVideoAdForZone:@"vzf8fb4670a60e4a139d01b5" withDelegate:nil];

}

error Log:
ADCOLONY 2.4.13.11 [*** ERROR** ] Disabling AdColony due to exception: +[NSData adc_dataWithWeaklyEncryptedBase64EncodedString:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3b158804
2014-11-01 14:37:06.460 VideoProject[805:60b] ADCOLONY 2.4.13.11 [ **ERROR ***] AdColony previously encountered an exception. Ignoring AdColony API call.

Please help me.I using xcode 5.1 and arc is enable

Answer (score 1):

Do you add the Linker flags.
befor I add the Linker flags,I also got the error--"AdColony previously encountered an exception. Ignoring AdColony API call."

The Adcolony document say like this:

Add two separate linker flags to `Target > Build Settings > Linking > Other` Linker Flags:

-ObjC
-fobjc-arc (this allows AdColony to use ARC even if your project does not)

Comment: You are right this problem occurs when you dont have the ObjC linker flag, do you know if there s a light alternative to this ? our app is mostly in C++ and you removed the flag to save space on exe size.

Comment: @N-AccessDev you can try to use the -force_load flag to replace the ObjC linker flag.     `-force_load $(SOURCE_ROOT)/adFramework/AdColony.framework/Versions/Current/AdColony `